# Workaround - Safari does not respect the hidden attribute on select > option elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, mobile-safari, html-select

I was developing an HTML form and realised that the behaviour of the select field was quite different on iOS Safari to other browsers (including several android based browsers).

Safari mobile was ignoring the `hidden` attribute of my `option` elements, allowing the user to select placeholder values. While it's possible to set the `disabled` attribute which prevents the user from selecting them on iOS, this still shows those fields to the user, and it has to be handled with media queries as then the option elements are not shown at all (even as placeholders) in other browsers.

I wanted a seamless universal solution. A bit of reading and experimentation indicated that Safari was actually stripping the hidden attribute and generating a popover from the `option`s.

Of course, if the option tag isn't there, it can't generate a popover containing them...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add event listeners to:

- `touchstart` & `touchend` to momentarily remove the option which should be hidden (note that it appears to be possible to trigger a tap without triggering touch end, if you swipe off the element while tapping)
- `change input` listener prevents the code from running more than once, and,
- `blur focusout touchcancel` listeners make doubly sure to reinstate the option if a user cancels selecting an option.

This code looks relatively long for what it is, but I've written it that way for readability. It could be significantly compressed, and the performance hit is negligible.

I have implemented it using jQuery, but I see no reason it couldn't be done with native JS and `querySelector()`.

This approach is quite robust to being accidentally triggered by other touch input (swiping, scrolling etc.), and is able to respond long before the `click` event occurs (which seems to occur after the popover has been generated).

It's not perfect, but it does bring the behaviour of Safari well into line with all other browsers in this small aspect.

Hope this helps someone else!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Workaround - Safari/Ios - does not respect the <option hidden> attribute
  //Momentarily remove the hidden option element when the user clicks a select element.
  //Re-Add it after iOS has generated its selection popover

  var hiddenOption; //Holds the option element we want to be non-selectable extra option)
  var timers = []; //Collect setTimout timers

  function returnOptionToSelect(element) {
    if ($(element).children('[data-ioshidden]').length > 0) {
      //It's already there. Do nothing.
    } else {
      $(element).prepend(hiddenOption); //Put it back
    }
  }

  $('#jQueryWorkaroundForm select').on('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).data('has-been-changed')) {
          //don't do anything
    } else {
      if($(e.target).children('[data-ioshidden]').length > 0){
        hiddenOption = $(e.target).children('[data-ioshidden]');
        $(hiddenOption).remove();
      }
      timers.push(setTimeout(returnOptionToSelect, 35, $(e.target))); //Nice short interval that's largely imperceptible, but long enough for the popover to generate
    }
  });

  $('#jQueryWorkaroundForm select').on('input', function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).data('has-been-changed')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      $(e.target).data('has-been-changed', true);
      if (navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.userAgent.includes('Safari') && !navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome')){
        $(e.target).prop('selectedIndex', (e.target.selectedIndex+1)); //Need to bump the index +1 on ios
      }
      //make sure the option is gone
      for (var x in timers) {
        clearTimeout(x);
      }
      timers = [];
      if ($(e.target).children('[data-ioshidden]').length > 0) {
        $(e.target).children('[data-ioshidden]').remove();
      }
      hiddenOption = undefined; //throw away the option so it can't get put back
    }
  });

  $('#jQueryWorkaroundForm select').on('blur focusout touchcancel', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).data('has-been-changed')) {
      //The user selected an option. Don't put the element back.
    } else {
      //The user did not select an option.
      if ($(e.target).children('[data-ioshidden]').length > 0) {
        //It's already there. Do nothing.
      } else {
        $(e.target).prepend(hiddenOption); //Put it back
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
select{
width:300px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>jQuery Workaround</p>
  <form id="jQueryWorkaroundForm">
    <select>
      <option hidden data-ioshidden value="">This option not selectable in any browser</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <p>Standard HTML</p>
  <form id="standardHTMLForm">
    <select>
      <option value="" hidden>This option selectable in iOS Safari</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And here it is as a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wjcprbyg/97/